# What were George Washington's beliefs behind the Church of England and Catholic practice?

Tags: political-history, george-washington

After the Puritans and Pilgrims fled from England to America, Britain would begin to become divided in its ways of political and religious tradition being opposed. But the Puritans, as well as the Separatists and Quakers, saw what was wrong with the Church of England and desired to commit to change. The Puritans and the Quakers were more for reforming the Catholic practices of England's church, but the separatists were against them the entire way. They were the first to plan an escape from Charles I, led by John Robinson, who drifted to New England on the Mayflower.

Once the 17th century had ended, the conflict would begin to rise for America to seek complete independence from England. What did General Washington find wrong with the Church of England and what led to his presidency? As president, did he represent what the puritans and separatists found wrong with Catholicism by implementing the teachings of Martin Luther and the reformers? 
You can learn other interesting facts about each US president here.
[http://sni.ps/S3z](http://all-that-is-interesting.com/us-presidents-facts?utm_campaign=pdsnips&utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social)

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but I'm wondering about what your research about George Washington told you, and why you think he had any religion other than Anglican.  Be sure to edit direct quotes into your question.

Comment: COE split from R. Catholic church under Henry VIII in the 16th century; the topic was well settled by the 18th century.  I'm not aware that he objected to CoE (other than the requirement that the King of England be the head of the church - hence Anglicanism).  I think this question would benefit from preliminary research.  I'm afraid I just can't understand the first sentence. (and the Pilgrims didn't flee from England to America).

Comment: I have to vote to close and request the question be revised with more historical facts.

Comment: Well, Anglican is either the same or close to the protestant church. I was wondering about the opinions on how the Catholic Church is very different from the Protestant Church and was change from England's Catholic Church being implemented at that time in America.

Comment: George Washington was a devout Mason; though there is the George Washington pew within St. Paul's Church in Downtown Manhattan.  It is possible that George Washington may have been both an Anglican Protestant Christian and a Mason, though his devotion and dedication to the Virginia Masons, is well chronicled.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: The Pilgrims sojourned for a dozen years in the Netherlands first, near Leiden, but originated in England and ended up at Plymouth Rock. That counts as "*fleeing England for (first the Netherlands and then) the Americas*" to me.

Comment: I was under the impression that the Pilgrims had traveled-(or as you said, "sojourned") initially, to Amsterdam.  I believe there is a Church in Amsterdam which housed Pilgrim worshipers.

Comment: You might want to go over [Religious_views_of_George_Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_views_of_George_Washington)

Comment: -1 and vtc Though a mere Brit, i was totally unaware that Washington had any **religious** motivation for his support of the War of Independence, and I'm baffled by references to Quakers and Puritans (an imprecise term anyway).

Answer (score 4):

While Washington was generally reticent about his personal religious beliefs (or lack thereof), many think that he was a Deist (like many of the other Founding Fathers), paying only lip service to organized Christianity. and mostly for its societal effects - that is, that it helped establish public order & morality.

What led to his Presidency was his generalship in the Revolution, and the almost universal admiration that Americans had for him.  It had nothing whatsoever to do with the Church of England/Episcopalians, Catholics, or any other religion.  Nor did the American Revolution arise out of religious differences.  Most if not all of your question seems to bear no relation at all to actual history.

You can find out a lot more by simply typing "george washington religious beliefs" into a search engine.  Google gives about 640K hits.